# Function to recognize control overlap

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone

Is there any function to recognize that two controls have overlap in xcode?

i can recognize it with position of them on view but want to do it with function beacuase i have many controls on view.

Comment: Isn't it a bad design, if the controls overlap ?

Comment: No because it's a game !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CGRectIntersectsRect()` with controls' frames as arguments.